# Why am I getting compilation error on this lambda

Tags: java

In the following piece of code I am getting compilation error:

```
error: method method1 in class MyClass cannot be applied to given types;
                MyClass.method1(MyClass.method2());
```

however if I store MyClass in a variable at line 1, the error is gone

```
var myVar = MyClass.method2();
MyClass.method1(myVar);
```

Here is the source:

```
class Test {
static void doSomething(Runnable c) {}

static void main() {
    doSomething(() -> {
        class MyClass {
            static void method1(MyClass myClass1) {}
            static MyClass method2() {return new MyClass();}
        }
        MyClass.method1(MyClass.method2());        //Line 1
    });
    }
}
```

What is the possible reason for this?

Thanks!

Comment: My compiler says `static` is not allowed. What version of java do you use?

Comment: [There is a pretty recent bug report about this.](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8295019?jql=text%20~%20%22local%20class%20in%20lambda%22) Is it you who reported it?

Comment: Ok I guess I was missing something.. some one else has reported it..

Answer (score -2):

This is a compiler bug in OpenJDK: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8295019

Comment: Then why does storing it in a var does not give error.

Comment: This answer is entirely wrong. @knittl - open an editor and try it. Write this: `class Test { public static void main(String[] args) { class WaitWhatClassesInsideMethodsWhatVoodooMagicIsThis {} }}`. Compile it and marvel.

Comment: Brainfart. You are absolutely right.